# Troubleshoot to trigger web api action method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I work on my web api project.

I have two get action methods in controller.

Here the controller:

```
namespace Playground.Web.Controllers.API
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/DamageEvent/{actionType}")]
    public class DamageEventController : ApiController
    {
        #region API methods
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDamageEvent(int damageEventId = 0)
        {
           //some logic 
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{ddd:int}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDamageEvent2(int ddd = 0)
        {
           //some logic 
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here WebApiConfig defenition:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

Here the example of URL in fiddler compose to  trigger web api action:

```
http://localhost/playground/api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22
```

I expect that for the URL above the **GetDamageEvent2** web api action will be fired. But instead `GetDamageEvent` action method is fired.

Why GetDamageEvent2 not fired? Any idea what do I am missing?

==============================**Update**================================

After I red answer from **Nkosi**

I made some changes to my code, I added to class WebApiConfig new route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And here the changes in action type:

```
namespace Playground.Web.Controllers.API
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/DamageEvent")]
    public class DamageEventController : ApiController
    {
        #region API methods
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetDamageEvent/{damageEventId}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDamageEvent(int damageEventId = 0)
        {
           //some logic 
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetDamageEvent2/{ddd}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDamageEvent2(int ddd = 0)
        {
           //some logic 
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

After I make the changes above the I tryed to fire the both actions and it worked.

But the problem now is when I try to call another actions in another controllers, For example:

```
http://localhost/playground/api/Contracts/1
```

I get 404 error.

So I guess the error occures because of the new route template.

So my question how can I fix the error above and to take  the new route template into consideration only when the URI try to access to DamageEventController?

Comment: You are going to have to show the controller that is not working otherwise we'll be making assumptions as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I reread new issue and it could be an ordering issue with your routes. Framework uses first matched route. Try switching the order of the two convention based routes.

Comment: @Nkosi , I switched route order templates.When I try to access DamageEvent controller I get 405 error.

Comment: The new convention route you added. Do you need it for anything other than `DamageEventController`? If not then you can safely remove that route and keep your default as `DamageEventController` is fully using attribute routing.

Comment: @Nkosi You mean from actionAPI from WebApiConfig?

Comment: Yes. thats the problem route

Comment: Yes I tryed to remove it.But steel when I try to trigger actions in  DamageEvent controller I get 405 error :(

Comment: Are you still accessign it using `http://localhost/playground/api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22`? if you are you need to use `http://localhost/playground/api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/22` so that you can remove convention route that is causing conflict.

Comment: Greate now it works I tryed this http://localhost/playground/api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22 before

Comment: So just to confirm. You removed the problem route. Are making your calls to `DamageEventController` using proper format and your previous routes work as they did before?

Comment: @Nkosi , yeas it works fine.But still I cant get why this ?ddd=22 made problem

Comment: If you looked the route attribute template it is looking for `.../{paramaterName}` in convention based routing the framework would match `?parameterName=value`. It would take the parameter name and look for a route with matching name. like `api/Contracts/1` and `api/Contracts?id=1`. That is not the case for attribute routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing attribute routing and convention based routing.

Nothing matches your `RoutePrefix` because there are no actions in the controller that has both a `{actionType}` **and** `{ddd}` templates.

But your stated URL...

```
api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22
```

...matches the `DefaultApi` convention based route for `GetDamageEvent` in the route table because it does not have a `[RouteAttribute]` and it defaults back the convention where...

```
api/{controller=DamageEvent}/{id=GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22}
```

Take a look at [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) to understand the convention based routing.

and also [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

> Each entry in the routing table contains a route template. The default
>   route template for Web API is "api/{controller}/{id}". In this
>   template, "api" is a literal path segment, and {controller} and {id}
>   are placeholder variables.
>
> When the Web API framework receives an HTTP request, it tries to match
>   the URI against one of the route templates in the routing table. If no
>   route matches, the client receives a 404 error. For example, the
>   following URIs match the default route:

```
/api/DamageEvent
/api/DamageEvent/1
/api/DamageEvent/GetDamageEvent2/?ddd=22
```

> Once a matching route is found, Web API selects the controller and the
>   action:
>
> - To find the controller, Web API adds "Controller" to the value of the {controller} variable.
> - To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name. For
>     example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action that starts
>     with "Get...", such as **"GetDamageEvent"**.  This
>     convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. You can
>     enable other HTTP methods by using attributes on your controller.
>     We’ll see an example of that later.
> - Other placeholder variables in the route template, such as {id}, are mapped to action parameters.

To get your stated route to work you need to update your route templates. Either the attribute route or add a new convention route to the route table

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helped me to understand some points.
But unfortunately while adding new route template,  other URI queries to other actions in other controllers makes  troubles.I updated my question. please check my update.